# Get difference between two numbers in WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the difference between two numbers (one of the values in a column and one arbitrary one) and then check if the difference is less than .20 in a `WHERE` statement. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE (`lowest_price` - 5) >= .20 OR (5 - `lowest_price`) <= .20
```

(where `5` is the arbitrary number, and `lowest_price` is the column I'm comparing it to)

However, when I run this statement, I get results that I'm not expecting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to convert the expression to a decimal,or add 0 before the dot.It would help to detail what were you expecting and what are you getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statement is wrong

Try `SELECT * FROM products WHERE (lowest_price - 5.0) BETWEEN -0.2 and 0.2`

You could try `SELECT (lowest_price - 5.0), * FROM products WHERE (lowest_price - 5.0) BETWEEN -0.2 and 0.2` which will help you where you are going wrong.